# Need a SQL query to get a single, max date when the max date is not unique

Tags: sql, oracle

My apologies if this has been asked and wasn't able to find this.  I've searched for a long time, with no luck.

My table is named RESULT -

```
DATE                     TEST_NUM   RESULT_NUM
11/16/2010 09:27:11 AM   123456      123111      
11/16/2010 09:27:11 AM   123456      123222
11/16/2010 09:27:11 AM   123456      123333
```

For a given TEST_NUM, I only want to return the max date just one time, and it doesn't matter what the other column entries are -

11/16/2010 09:27:11 AM   123456      123111

```
SELECT  RESULT.DATE,
        RESULT.RESULT_NUM,
        RESULT.TEST_NUM
 FROM RESULT
 WHERE RESULT.TEST_NUM = 123456 
 AND RESULT.DATE =  (SELECT  MAX(R1.DATE)
                      FROM RESULT R1
                      WHERE r1.TEST_NUM = RESULT.TEST_NUM)
```

But as you guessed, I don't get 1 result - I get all three.  I've tried everything!  Please help this newbie!

Comment: A single max date from what? Can you post more information about what tables you have and what you need?

Comment: `MAX(SomeColumn)` will return one value so in that sense it is "unique". There can, however, be several rows that contain that same value. Are you asking how to select one of these rows? If so, what criteria do you wish to use for that selection?

Comment: yes exactly.  I actually have complete flexibility to choose - I included 'result_num' as the most likely criteria.

Answer (score 6):

To get the maximum date:

```
SELECT MAX(RESULT.DATE) FROM RESULT
```

To get an entire row for any one of the rows that hold the maximum date:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM RESULT
    WHERE RESULT.TEST_NUM = 123456
    ORDER BY RESULT.DATE DESC
)
WHERE rownum = 1
```

Comment: Mark, This is very useful and very close.  I need to tweak it a bit to fit into my larger query but it looks like this will work.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** : -

```
select max(DATE) from  RESULT where RESULT.TEST_NUM = 123456 group by RESULT.TEST_NUM
```

Here is an example -

```
select id,max (date_column) from your_table group by id
```

where id is the column you want the values for max date for, this will give you max date for each of the unique entries for id in that table out of the many date entries, since what I understood was that you have multiple dates and want the max.

Comment: the problem is my entries won't be unique - and I have the flexibility taking any of them, as the only thing I need is the date.

Comment: Misnomer, This does help.  I need to work out a few details with your updated response, but I think this will work.  Thanks for responding both times, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Why won't this work

```
SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM TABLE
```

Comment: `TOP 1` is not valid for Oracle

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You're right.. it doesn't even make sense anyway... I'm one exhausted idiot :/

Comment: this doesn't return just 1 result, any that match the MAX date are returned.

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT date_column FROM table GROUP BY date_column HAVING COUNT(*)>1 ORDER BY date_column DESC LIMIT 1

This will return the highest date_column ( ORDER BY date_column DESC ) that is not unique ( HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 )

Comment: sorry for the reply, this has been made unuseful after the user added informations about the question :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct max(date_column) 
into variable
from table
where condition;
```

Adding the distinct will ensure that if the data is the same then it will only return one record.

Comment: this works, except I want multiple columns returned besides the date_column.